# What will be the next two terms?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

> **$$26\quad 28\quad 28\quad 30\quad 30\quad 28\quad 32\quad 30\quad ?\quad ?$$**

If I consider the sequence of odd terms, then it follows increasing by $2$ each time. So the first missing term is  $34$. Also if I consider the sequence of even terms then it oscillates, so the $2$nd missing term is $28$.

Am I correct? If I am, then I am looking for another beautiful logic.

Comment: So you want us to find another possibility for this sequence? Shouldn't this be too broad?

Comment: Yes, I want another possibility if my explanation is correct.

Comment: To me, your explanation seems to be the clearest approach. I started mentally composing an answer after seeing the sequence until I read the exact same thing in your question!

Comment: Don't you mean the first missing term is $34$, since $32+2=34$?

Comment: Yes.. I correct it. Thank you for mention it.

Answer (score 4):

It could be

> +2 +0 +2 +0 -2 +4 -2 +4 -6 +8 -6 +8 ....

Which would make the next few terms

> 34 and 28

But then again,
I can think of many many other possibilities, implying that this puzzle is way too broad.